# Get back the value list from an ncurses FIELD

Tags: c, ncurses

I want to get back the value list from an ncurses FIELD with type TYPE_ENUM. The value list has been set with this code:

```
const char* val_lst[] = { "type 1", "type 2", "type 3", NULL };
set_field_type(fields[OPT_VAL_FLD], TYPE_ENUM, val_lst, 0, 1);
```

Is this possible, and if so, how? I have seen the function

```
char *field_arg(FIELD *field);
```

but could not interpret the pointer it returns.

Comment: You probably want [`field_buffer`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_field_buffer.3x.html).

Comment: @Thomas Dickey: This gives me the current value. But what about the other values?

Answer (score 0):

That

```
char *field_arg(FIELD *field);
```

doesn't look like ncurses.  It's been **`void*`** since the initial version in 1995.  SVr4 used **`char*`**.

Either way, the result from [**`field_arg`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_field_validation.3x.html#h3-field_arg) is a pointer to an ***opaque*** structure called the *argument block*.  That is because each field-type has a different set of arguments which are copied into the argument block.

If you need to know the layout of the argument block, you would have to look at the source code (which differs between implementations):

- [ncurses](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/f21b57e07039e11e902d06eb1513f89c49836b0e/form/fty_enum.c#L40)

```
typedef struct
  {
    char **kwds;
    int count;
    bool checkcase;
    bool checkunique;
  }
enumARG;
```

- [NetBSD](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libform/type_enum.c?rev=1.12&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN)

```
typedef struct 
{
    char **choices;
    unsigned num_choices;
    bool ignore_case;
    bool exact;
} enum_args;
```

- [Solaris](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/13810335a5a8384eed97a8661536eb5352f0c933/usr/src/lib/libeti/form/common/ty_enum.c#L50)

```
typedef struct {

    char ** list;
    int checkcase;
    int checkuniq;
    int count;
} ENUM;
```

Comment: I must have seen it here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1471/field-arg-3curses.html